# Python openpyxl changng formats / datatypes

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to import an Excelfile (with OpenPyXl), change the datatypes / formats en export the file again.

```
import openpyxl

file_IN = (r"C:\Users\f\test_in.xlsx")
file_OUT = (r"C:\Users\f\test_out.xlsx")

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_IN)
ws = wb['STL']
col1 = ws.column_dimensions['B'] 'Date
col1.number_format = u'0'
col2 = ws.column_dimensions['X'] 'Origin
col1.number_format = u'0'

wb.save(file_OUT)
```

How do I change a string of a date dd/mm/yyyy to a datetime in Excel with the same format?
How do I change a string with value 2022042595202 that is visualized as a scientific notation to just a normal number format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found it (openpyxl)

```
def fix_datetype(myxlsfile):
    file = op.load_workbook(myxlsfile)
    print(myxlsfile)
    sheets = file.sheetnames
    print(sheets)
    sheet = file[sheets[0]]
    print(sheet)
    rows = sheet.max_row
    for i in range(2, rows + 1): 
        cell = 'B' + f'{i}'
        old_date = sheet[cell].value 
        value = datetime.datetime.strptime(old_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        sheet[cell].value = value
        sheet[cell].number_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy;@'
    file.save(myxlsfile)
```